# Vertical divider with icon on top

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical list of element and I want to add a divider that has bulb on top with an icon and is clickable.

For example like in the code bellow but where the divider has a circle on top with an icon( in the margin on top).

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.divider {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 4px;
  height:150px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: and what did you try to do till now? Post some code

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.divider {
   display: block;
   margin: 20px 0;
   text-align: center;
   min-height: 20px;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="divider">   <a href="#"><img src="https://icons-for-free.com/download-icon-lightbulb+outline+24px-131985192644521589_16.png"></a></div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```